# Java Maven Spring Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.surefire:surefire-junit-platform:pom:2.22.2 from/to central

Tags: java, spring, maven

Java Spring project fails to package the project with maven, printing the following error:

```
Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.surefire:surefire-junit-platform:pom:2.22.2 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Transfer failed for https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/surefire/surefire-junit-platform/2.22.2/surefire-junit-platform-2.22.2.pom
```

The use used pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>***</groupId>
    <artifactId>***</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>***</name>
    <description>***</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

I use IntelliJ to develop and build the project.
I do not need a proxy to enter the internet. If I click the link, I can see the pom file without problems. Reloading the project does not work, downloading all sources neither.

In the local storage, I find the following files:

```
C:\Users\***\.m2\repository\org\apache\maven\plugins\maven-surefire-plugin\2.22.2
    _remote.repositories
    maven-surefire-plugin-2.22.2.jar
    maven-surefire-plugin-2.22.2.jar.sha1
    maven-surefire-plugin-2.22.2.pom
    maven-surefire-plugin-2.22.2.pom.sha1
```

Removing them and reloading the project restores the files, the error persists.

I cleaned the project and used the `-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2` parameter no changes.

Edit:

Using a VPN doe not work.

Output of `mvn -v`:

```
Apache Maven 3.8.4 (9b656c72d54e5bacbed989b64718c159fe39b537)
Maven home: C:\Program Files\java\apache-maven-3.8.4
Java version: 1.8.0_312, vendor: Temurin, runtime: C:\Program Files\Eclipse Adoptium\jdk-8.0.312.7-hotspot\jre
Default locale: de_DE, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 10", version: "10.0", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"
```

When building with `mvn clean package -U`:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.2:test (default-test) on project Grafnus-Server: Unable to generate classpath: org.apache.maven.artifact.resolver.ArtifactResolutionException: Unable to get dependency information for org.apache.maven.surefire:surefire-junit-platform:jar:2.22.2: Failed to retrieve POM for org.apache.maven.surefire:surefire-junit-platform:jar:2.22.2: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.surefire:surefire-junit-platform:pom:2.22.2 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): transfer failed for https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/surefire/surefire-junit-platform/2.22.2/surefire-junit-platform-2.22.2.pom

[ERROR] from the specified remote repositories:
[ERROR]   central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2, releases=true, snapshots=false)
[ERROR] Path to dependency:
[ERROR]         1) dummy:dummy:jar:1.0
```

Comment: The problem: `Transfer failed for https://repo.` either network issue or firewall/proxy etc. First try to use plain command line...which Maven version do you use? The given TLS is usually only needed for JDK7...but not for JDK8... also turn on checksum policy (https://blog.soebes.de/blog/2018/10/13/maven-artifact-checksums-what/) also try to build via `mvn ... -U` (plain command line)...

Comment: @khmarbaise Edited the post

Comment: sorry, cannot reproduce on [intializer project](https://start.spring.io/#!type=maven-project&language=java&platformVersion=2.6.0&packaging=jar&jvmVersion=1.8&groupId=com.example&artifactId=demo&name=demo&description=Demo%20project%20for%20Spring%20Boot&packageName=com.example.demo&dependencies=web,data-jpa,h2)

Comment: The used JDK 8 is a bit out of date (1.8.0_41) ...JDK8 is something like 1.8.0_300?...

Comment: @khmarbaise I have updated my version and updated the output in the question

Comment: @xerx593 I used the dependence WEB, JPA and H2 in the initializer

Comment: The error keeps the same as described? Yes then you have network issues (VPN?)

Comment: @khmarbaise I have tried to use the normal connection (Home Wi-Fi without restrictions) as well as a VPN (Bitdefender VPN various locations). The problem persists.

Comment: The issue is the network...where I can't help...nor is it fault of Maven...

Comment: @khmarbaise this has nothing to do with java version, to me. We reproduce it in `spring-cloud-kubernetes` build itself, on JDK-17. It has to be a networking issue, as we have two pipelines `circleci` and `github actions`, and we have never seen this on `circleci`.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was the outdated java version. I updated to a newer one and at first I did not change it in the project settings (thought that would change on his own). Now it works like a charm. Thanks to @khmarbaise

Comment: Thanks for confirming what worked for you, but it could help readers if you'd clarify in tour answer both what the original Java was (1.8.0_41?) vs what you changed to (1.8.0_312?). I add the question marks as I'm trying to discern things from all that's been shared. Since you comment that you "updated the output" (in our original question), someone looking at that question and your answer here alone would not readily be able to tell what was your starting and ending points--and that could help future readers who may have the same problem and find this post .